# OpenCV image resize comparison to matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

here is my function

```
int* Utilities::MatlabImresize(int* channel,int width, int height, double scale)
{
    cv::Mat src(width, height, CV_32F);
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
    {
        src.at<float>(i) = channel[i];      
    }
    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::resize(src, dst, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5,cv::INTER_CUBIC);
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\gdarmon\\Desktop\\OpenCV_CR.txt");
    myfile << dst;
    myfile.close();

    return NULL;
}
```

As discussed in my previous question [imresize - trying to understand the bicubic interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823140/imresize-trying-to-understand-the-bicubic-interpolation)
I have recompiled openCV with `-0.5f` instead of `-0.75f`

however I still get different results although the input is the same, I guess i'm using resize() function wrong... can you please help?

the matlab code is just

```
Gr = imresize(Gr, 0,5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That change to OpenCV only makes the interpolation kernels' formulas match.  It does not enable anti-aliasing. The result here will match with

```
imresize(A,scale,'bicubic','AntiAliasing',false)
```

To match the default, you'd need to further modify the kernel, making it broader.

Comment: I remember a very nice discussion between you and Amro about this.  +1

Comment: @chappjc ohh I thought the whole point was to match the default..., anyway thank you i will try to work with this.

Comment: @Gilad No, the point was to make anything match.  Without fixing the coefficients, that couldn't happen.